# Help with insert query which replaces an original id with different value in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

**UPDATE**: Adding more `Employee` and `ReplacementEmployee`

Table `Employee` -

```
 EmployeeId   SerialNo
 ----------------------------- 
 1             11111  
 34            23233    
 23            13234
```

Table `ReplacementEmployee`-

```
 ReplacementId   SerialNo
 ----------------------------- 
 11            11111  
 23            23233    
 13            13234
```

So when I join these tables on Serial No. have something like this `Mapping Table` -

```
 EmployeeId   ReplacementId
 ----------------------------- 
 1             11    
 34            23    
 23            13
```

So now I have insert all the data from table something like this `OrignalTable` and it can have multiple values for EmployeeId-

```
 EmployeeId   Name
 ----------------------------- 
 1             AAA    
 34            BBB    
 23            CCC  
 1             AAA
```

Into an table with different schema with basically something like this `InsertTable` and it can have multiple values for EmployeeId-

```
ReplacementId       Name
------------------------------- 
 11                AAA   
 23                BBB
 13                CCC  
 11                AAA
```

So if you look at the problem I need to `insert` data from one table to other but I need to insert a different field i.e. in this case I need to insert the `corresponding` `ReplacementId` instead of the `EmployeeId` in the new table. So can anyone suggest me how would I go about writing such a query ?

Comment: Why are there duplicate entries in an employees table, and why do you want to continue duplicating employees?

Comment: I have updated my question with some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
INESRT INTO InsertTable (ReplacementID, [Name])
SELECT R.ReplacementID, O.[Name]
FROM OriginalTable O
INNER JOIN Employee E ON E.EmployeeID = O.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN ReplacementEmployee R ON E.SerialNo = R.SerialNo
```

And if you only want ONE instance of each employee in the InsertTable, use `SELECT DISTINCT` instead